# Regex Expression for strings which look like javascript objects in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

We have strings in php like the following two examples:

```
{{'LANGUAGE_ID','String inclusive special chars (,/)'}}
{{'LANGUAGE_ID','String inclusive special chars (,/)','Another string inclusive special chars (,/)'}}
```

The strings are always surrounded by `{{` and `}}`. Inside we have multiple elements separated by a comma and surrounded by single quotes. The first element is always a word `\w`. After that we have a unknown number of elements which can be a word or sentence including special characters. What we want to get is the content (text between single quotes) for each element.

We have a solution as long as we know how many elements the string contains.

Solution for 1. example: `{{'([\w]+)','([^\n\r']+)'}}`

Solution for 2. example: `{{'([\w]+)','([^\n\r']+)','([^\n\r']+)'}}`

We are looking for a solution which works for both examples or even a example with three or more elements.

We have a regex share to play around here:
http://regexr.com/3c58c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex using `\G`:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:{{|\G,)'([^']+)'(?=.*?}})/', $text, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jV2jN1/3)

Comment: \R matches a capital R. I don't think it's necessary. Works with just ```(?:{{|\G,)'([^\']+)'(?=.*?}})``` - Perhaps he was attempting to do a return? \r?

Comment: Mike is right, `\R` is not even needed here. See updated answer. btw `\R` matches any newline character but it shouldn't be used in `[...]`

Comment: it does work. Thanks. But to be honest I don't understand the `\G`, would you be so kind and give me a short explanation?

Comment: `\G` assert position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match. So in our example it matches position after `{{` then after `'([^']+)'` match it matches comma after that match and it keeps on matching that until it gets `}}`

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
{{'([\w]+)',('([^\n\r']+)',*)*}}
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted it into my regexr link and it doesn't look correct

Comment: With this expression, both lines in regexr are highlighted

Comment: This has been flagged as low quality.  Please edit your answer and explain each of the steps in it.